# Return Places nearbysearch with only 'my' locations loaded to 'Bulk Uload Tool' against my API/ID

Tags: google-places-api

GOAL:

I am working to return a result set of locations via the types=other parameter so that I can ensure ONLY MY locations are part of the result set.

Question/Scenario 1:

I am able to submit place/add for a location and retrieve that location with nearbysearch, however I am not able to add all my data via this method such as hours, image, url, etc.  Is there formatting to support this data upload in the place/add?

Question/Scenario 2:

I have uploaded my locations in the 'Bulk Upload Tool' under my ID that is associated to my API key.  In the upload I included the category 'Other'.  None of these locations return in my nearbysearch result set.  Should they return?  If so, does anyone have insight to how?